# How to perform undo and redo functionality in angular?

Tags: html, angular, typescript, dom

Here, in my application, I need to implement the undo and redo functionality in one parent component. I also have a number of child components, and each of these child components contains one or more DOM elements, such as a textbox, checkbox, and delete icon.
So, in this case, if I make any changes to any DOM elements that are present in the child components, the changes should be detected and sent to the parent component so that it may perform an undo and redo.
•   Undo is possible for the last five actions.
•   Redo is available for the last five undo actions.

```
`<!-- Main component -->
<div>
    <div>
        <div>
            <div>
                <header [section]="section" [formType]="formType" [sectionIndex]="sectionIndex"  [first]="first" [last]="last"></header>
            </div>
            <div >
               <item-crud [section]="section" [formType]="formType" [sectionIndex]="sectionIndex"> </item-crud>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

<!-- header -->
<div class="container">
    <div class="col-md-5 pull-right vertical-center"><i (click)="undo()"></i><i (click)="redo()"></i></div>
</div>
</div>

<!-- item-crud  -->
    <div id="accord">
        <div>
            <div>
                <div>
                    <div class="formContainer">
                        <div><date-stamp></date-stamp></div>
                        <div><text-field [sectionItem]="sectionItem"></text-field></div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div> `
```

In this case, if I make any changes to any DOM elements that are present in the child components, the changes should be detected and sent to the parent component so that it should perform an undo and redo for all the changes done.

Comment: If you're using reactive forms (which I think you should be), you simply subscribe to the `valueChanges` of the form and record the changes, generally in a service. That way, you can roll back to a previous state by simply calling `setState` on the `FormGroup` and passing the previous state.

Comment: @WillAlexander - Thanks for responding... Do you have any examples of how to record and store the changes in the service?

Comment: My apologies, it should be setValue and not setState. As for how to record, you could simply create an array and add the latest state to the top, for example.